# fontspec issue with new LaTeX <2020-02-02> patch level 1

Tags: luatex, fontspec

Let's compile this file with LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} % (or any other font)

\newfontfamily\myfont{texgyreheros}[
   Extension =      .otf,
   UprightFont =    *-regular,
   BoldFont =       *-bold,
   ItalicFont =     *-italic,
   BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic,
   Ligatures=TeX
  ]

\begin{document}
\showoutput

\section{\myfont Bold and \textit{italic} \bfdefault}
AAA
\end{document}
```

The .log file says:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/texgyreheros(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/texgyreheros(0)/m/n' instead on input line 17.


 LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/texgyreheros(0)/bx/it' undefined
 (Font)              using `TU/texgyreheros(0)/bx/n' instead on input line 17.
```

and the PDF output is not correct (no bold, no bolditalic):

[image]

Two questions:

1. LaTeX complains about a `TU/texgyreheros(0)/bx/n` missing font while `\bfdefault` is `b`, not `bx` in the section title, why?

   Please note that the same document compiles as expected with LaTeX `<2019-10-01> patch level 3`, `\bfdefault` being expanded as `bx`.
2. When uncommenting the `\setmainfont{...}` line (with any font), the output is correct, `\bfdefault` expands again as `b` and no warning appears in the `.log` file. The section title is printed as expected in `\TU/texgyreheros(0)/b/n/14.4`.

Is a `\setmainfont{...}` statement necessary even if the output is to be printed with the default LMR fonts? I see that the `.log` file differs if an explicit `\setmainfont{LaTin Modern Roman}` is added: `\TU/lmr/m/n/10 AAA` versus `\TU/LatinModernRoman(0)/m/n/10 AAA`.

Comment: looks like a bug.

Comment: I see same can you report it at https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues ? (or we could..)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would be grateful if you could do so:  I am not comfortable with github :-(

Comment: We are looking at it and it will probably be resolved soon.

Answer (score 4):

It is not really a bug but a behavior that could be improved on in one way or the other.

The point is, the document has LMR as it is document font with "bx" as the bold `\rmfamily`.
So `\section` calls `\bfseries` and that makes the series attribute become "bx" (remember we are still in `\rmfamily`at this point).

Now `\myfont` comes along and only changes the family name, thus requesting `texgyreheros(0)/bx` which hasn't been set up by `fontspec`. Thus normal NFSS substitution happens and you get `texgyreheros(0)/n`.

The reason why `\setmainfont` appears to work is because it changes the document font to a "b" font (in case of of Latin Modern Roman actually incorrectly).

Here is an example for pdftex that shows the different behaviors and causes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{ptm}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}{<-> ptmr7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ptm}{m}{sc}{<-> ptmrc7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ptm}{m}{sl}{<-> ptmro7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ptm}{m}{it}{<-> ptmri7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ptm}{b}{n}{<-> ptmb7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ptm}{b}{sc}{<-> ptmbc7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ptm}{b}{sl}{<-> ptmbo7t}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ptm}{b}{it}{ <-> ptmbi7t}{}

\def\test{0}      % ok
\def\test{1}      % ????
\def\test{2}      % ok - typical pdftex case

\ifcase \test\relax
  \renewcommand\rmdefault{ptm}
\or  % 1
\or  % 2
  \DeclareFontShape{OT1}{ptm}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * ptm/b/n}{}
\fi

\showoutput

\begin{document}

\sffamily     Text ``cmss/m/n''

\bfseries     Text ``cmss/bx/n''

\ifcase \test\relax
  \rmfamily
\else
  \fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
\fi

Text ``ptm/bx/n'' changed to ``ptm/b/n''?


\bigskip \mdseries

Summary: \LaTeX\ understands about fonts with different ``boldness'' if they
are assigned to the metafamilies ``rm'' ``sf'' or ``tt''.

However, if you change to an arbitrary family then the current
``boldness'' remains (e.g., bx) and it depends on the family setup
having a substitution rule for ``bx'' to ``b'' (which nearly all fonts
for pdfTeX have) to work.

\end{document}
```

Thus short term, one solution would be that fontspec adds the necessary substitution rules, e.g. in this case

```
\DeclareFontShape{TU}{texgyreheros(0)}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * texgyreheros(0)/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{TU}{texgyreheros(0)}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * texgyreheros(0)/b/it}{}
```

Midterm NFSS should probably more generally support different "boldness" per family.
I have opened an issue for that on our tracker: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/275